# bash command not executing after screen

Tags: bash, rsync

bash

```
screen -dmS name rsync -ave ssh --progress user@hostname:path/to/src /path/to/dest --bwlimit=2500

find "/path/to/dest" -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find "/path/to/dest" -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

In this script folders get their permissions changed but not files. the command for files doesnt work.  Ive tested thew command for files separately and it work outside of the script. if I pass a different command to screen insteadof rsyc it works...

Im trying to use a scrypt to launch rsync in a screen so I can attach to monito progress but set permission after.. advice / comments

Comment: What happen if you change it to
screen -dm -S name -- rsync -ave ssh --progress user@hostname:path/to/src /path/to/dest --bwlimit=2500

Comment: Are you waiting for `rsync` to finish before running the `find` commands? Because if you aren't then the files may not exist yet.

Comment: some test fiiles already exist in that location and don't get their permissions changed. I tried the suggested and the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can use -chmod=D2775,F664 to accomplish the same thing directly through rsync

Answer (score 1):

You could have rsync change the permissions and skip the find commands.

Something like this:

```
screen -S name -d -m rsync -av --chmod=Dug=rwx,Do=rx,Fu=rw,Fg=rw,Fo=r -p -e ssh --progress user@hostname:path/to/src /path/to/dest --bwlimit=2500
```

`D` is for directory

`F` is for file

`u` is for user

`g` is for group

`o` is for others